# View not refreshing after successful http.get from factory (chained promises in use)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have read more tutorials and posts on this particular subject than I care to admit but I still haven't been able to locate a solution.  I need the view to refresh after the chained promise returns which is bound to $scope.p.devices.  I have tried disabling cached views (still disabled) and a number of other solutions.  Hoping someone on here can point me in the proper direction.

HTML:
    
    
    
      Device List

```
  <md-card>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="device-content-detail"
          collection-repeat="device in p.devices"
          collection-item-height="136px"
          collection-item-width="100%">
          <div class="card-content">
              <h1 class="md-title">
                      <span>
                          <i class="fa fa-crosshairs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Device List
                      </span>
              </h1>
          {{device.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </md-card>
```

```
    <md-list>
        <md-card ng-if="!isAnimated" class="card-item" ng-repeat="device in p.devices track by $index">
                <md-card-content>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h1 class="md-title">
                                <span>
                                  Device List
                                    <i class="fa fa-crosshairs" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{device.name}}
                                </span>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="device-content-detail">
                            <i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{device.connected}}
                            <i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{device.last_heard}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
```

Controller:

```
appControllers.controller('devicesCtrl', function ($scope,$state,$stateParams,$timeout,$mdDialog,$ionicHistory,$ionicLoading,particle,pDevices,safeparse) {
//$scope.isAnimated is the variable that use for receive object data from state params.
//For enable/disable row animation.
var debug = true;
$ionicLoading.show({
  content: 'Getting Devices',
  animation: 'fade-in',
  showBackdrop: true,
  maxWidth: 200,
  showDelay: 0
});

$timeout(function () {
  pDevices.getpDevices().then(function(data) {
    $scope.p.devices = data;
    if (debug) console.log(debug + 'time out got particle.io device list: ', $scope.p.devices);
    $scope.isLoading = false;
    if (debug) console.log(debug + 'time out complete, hiding ionicLoading: ');
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }, function() {
    $scope.p.showAlertDialog($event);
    $scope.error = 'unable to load devices'
    });
  }, 2000);

$scope.initialForm = function () {
    //$scope.isLoading is the variable that use for check statue of process.
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    $scope.isAnimated =  $stateParams.isAnimated;
};// End initialForm.

$scope.$watch('p.devices', function (newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal, oldVal)
  });

$scope.p = {
  currentDevice: '',
  deviceId: particle.setDevice(),
  token: particle.setToken(),
  devices: [],

  getDevices: function () {
        pDevices.getpDevices().then(function(deviceList) {
          if (debug) console.log(debug + 'getDevices got particle.io device list: ', deviceList);
          $scope.p.devices = deviceList.data;
        });
      },

  // Select the current device for particle platform
  setDevice: function (deviceId) {
    if (deviceId) {
      if (debug) console.log(debug + 'setDevice', deviceId);
      $scope.p.deviceId = deviceId;
      particle.setDevice(deviceId);
      $scope.startup();
    }
    return $scope.p.deviceId;
  }
};

showAlertDialog = function ($event) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: 'DialogController',
        templateUrl: 'confirm-dialog.html',
        targetEvent: $event,
        locals: {
            displayOption: {
                title: "No Devices Found.",
                content: "Unable to load Device List.",
                ok: "Confirm"
            }
        }
    }).then(function () {
        $scope.dialogResult = "You choose Confirm!"
    });
}// End showAlertDialog.
$scope.initialForm();
});// End of controller Device.
```

And finally the factory being called:

```
appServices.factory('pDevices', function($http, localstorage) {
root_url = 'https://api.particle.io/v1/'
  var getpDevices = function() {
return $http.get(root_url + 'devices').then(function(response){
  console.log('pDevices getpDevices: ', response.data);
  return response.data;
  });
};
  return {
  getpDevices: getpDevices
  };
});
```

Screenshot of what I get:
[image: Resulting View]

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.$apply();`? Sometimes the scope needs to be nudged that it needs to be refreshed.

Comment: I have, but in all my reading I see that it is generally considered a bad practice.  When I did try it I got a Digest is already in progress error.

Comment: In the `$timeout` the code does `$scope.p.devices = data;`. The  `$scope.p.getDevices` function does `$scope.p.devices = deviceList.data;`. Which one is giving you problems?

Comment: Both really. I tried to use the timeout ionicLoading to hold up the view render and get the deviceLiat first but can now see that it doesn't work that way. My debug statements show that it goes main controller, timeout then scope.p. None of which cause the view to render with the results of my http request. I thought that it should render on a scope variable change automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was entirely in my HTML/SASS div tags as well as my object array which was not device but Object.  This is working but needing some formatting corrections.

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" title="Device List">
<!--note list section-->
<ion-content id="device-list-content" class="bg-white">
  <md-list>
        <md-card class="card-item"
          collection-repeat="Object in p.devices"
          collection-item-height="136px"
          collection-item-width="100%">
          <md-divider></md-divider>
          <md-card-content>
              <div class="card-content">
                <h1 class="md-title-device">
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-crosshairs" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{Object.name}}
                        </span>
                </h1>
                <div class="device-content-detail">
                  <div ng-show="Object.connected">
                    <i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{Object.last_ip_address}}
                  </div>
                  <div ng-show="!Object.connected">
                    <i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{Object.last_heard}}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </md-card-content>
          </md-card>

    </md-list>
</ion-content>
```